# Homebrew install of node 8 installs npm v4 instead of v5

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew

From what I understand npm v5 should be included with node v8, like mentioned in the node [release blog](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v8.0.0/). However, after successfully installing node v8 via homebrew, the npm version is still `4.2.0`.

I initially upgraded from node v7, but a clean install yields the same result. Running `brew doctor` didn't help and I can't find any open issues on either the [node](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20npm%20) or [homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20node) projects.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Try [`npm install npm@latest -g`](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node).

Comment: Homebrew formulae and formula issues live in the [Homebrew/homebrew-core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/) repo, not Homebrew/brew. There's [an open issue for this](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/14085).

Comment: @JordanRunning Ah I didn't know they tracked it in the core repo, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/14085) is resolved, `brew install node` now correctly installs npm v5 :)